# How to Calculate "Average time between first visit and purchase per item_id"

Tags: mysql, sql

#### Average time between first visit and purchase per item_id?

I have two tables,

`event` and `trans`.

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `event_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE `trans` (
  `item_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp
)
```

Assume Values for event table(multiple user visits):

> ```
> |visit |a1 |2016-09-14 22:48:14 |
> |visit |a2 |2016-09-14 22:48:28 |
> |visit |a3 |2016-09-14 22:48:45 |
> |visit |a1 |2016-09-15 15:10:39 |
> |visit |a2 |2016-09-15 15:11:08 |
> |visit |a1 |2016-09-15 15:12:34 |
> ```

and for trans table

> ```
> |i1 |1 |100 |a1 |2016-09-15 15:12:22 |
> |i2 |2 |100 |a2 |2016-09-15 15:13:17 |
> |j1 |1 |140 |a1 |2016-09-15 16:12:22 |
> |j4 |3 |150 |a3 |2016-09-15 16:13:17 |
> ```

I wrote a Query to find Average time between first visit and first purchase across users.

```
SELECT AVG(timestampdiff(second, e.mintime, t.mintime))
FROM (SELECT user_id, min(time) AS mintime
      FROM event e
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) e JOIN
     (SELECT user_id, min(time) AS mintime
      FROM trans t
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) t
     ON e.user_id = t.user_id;
```

But now I want to find Average time between first visit and purchase per item_id.

For the above data, how can I write a query to find...

**Average time between first visit and purchase per item_id.**

Comment: The code looks like MySQL, not Postgres, so I removed the latter tag.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Edit your question and explain what "Average time between first visit and purchase per item_id" means to you.  Desired results would help.

Comment: And I've removed the <ansi-sql> tag since none of the answers are ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the average from the first visit to the purchase for each item *per user that purchases the item*.

If so, then you can just add `item_id` to the second subquery and then use it for aggregation in the outer query:

```
SELECT t.item_id, AVG(timestampdiff(second, e.mintime, t.mintime))
FROM (SELECT user_id, min(time) AS mintime
      FROM event e
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) e JOIN
     (SELECT user_id, item_id, min(time) AS mintime
      FROM trans t
      GROUP BY user_id, item_id
     ) t
     ON e.user_id = t.user_id
GROUP BY t.item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?  This is the closest thing I can come up with.

```
SELECT *, timestampdiff(second, e.`time`, t.`time`) as difference
FROM  `event` e
left join trans as t ON t.user_id = e.user_id  -- same use
    AND YEAR(e.`time`) =  YEAR(t.`time`) -- same year
    AND MONTH(e.`time`) =  MONTH(t.`time`) -- same month
    AND DAY(e.`time`) =  DAY(t.`time`) -- same day
    AND  t.`time` between e.`time` AND ADDTIME( e.`time`,"0:10:00") -- ten minutes RANGE
order by  e.user_id, YEAR(e.`time`), MONTH(e.`time`), DAY(e.`time`), e.`time`
;
```

I'm not sure which is the PARENT TABLE.  Try to switch the left join table declaration and remodify RANGE condition.